# Find largest average set of results in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array and I want to find the largest average set of results, so far I can calculate the average of each set of results but I'm not sure how to select the biggest from the output.

My code:

`static int[][] studentMarksArray = new int[10][3];`

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]*studentMarksArray[i][1]*studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
  System.out.println(total);
 }
```

An attempted solution:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]*studentMarksArray[i][1]*studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
  double newTotal = total;
  if(newTotal>total){
    newTotal = total;
    System.out.println(newTotal);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem? have you got any error?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: I'll include what I attempted, give me a min

Comment: in your code newTotal == total all the time.

Comment: That's where I'm having trouble of how to store the first calculated value and then compare it to the next calculated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
 double max = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]*studentMarksArray[i][1]*studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
   max = Math.max(max, total);
 }
```

or if you want the index:

```
 int index = -1;
 double max = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]*studentMarksArray[i][1]*studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;

   if(Math.max(max, total) == total) {
     index = i;
     max = total;
   }
 }
```

Ok if you want to have an array of averages at the end, do this:

```
int index = -1;
double max = 0;
double [] averages = new double[10];

 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]*studentMarksArray[i][1]*studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
   averages[i] = total;
   if(Math.max(max, total) == total) {
     index = i;
     max = total;
   }
 }
```

Comment: When I run your code the program is printing out all the averages for each set of marks

Comment: My code will produce you a maximum value of the sets and the index of that set. Or do you want something else?

Comment: I want to get the average of each set and then output the highest average

Comment: thats what it is doing.... in `max` you have the highest average and in `index` you have the corresponding index.

Comment: It worked when I tried it again, I must have made a typo the first time, apologies and thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

add this after variable initialisation

```
  int largest=0,lp=0;
```

add this before forloop ends but after calculating total

```
  if(largest<total){
    largest=total;lp=i;
  }
```

at the end of forloop you will have largest average in the variable largest and its position in variable i.

Comment: I have tried implementing your code but it is printing out all the average marks:

    `for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      double largest=0,lp=0;
      double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]*studentMarksArray[i][1]*studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
      if(largest<total){
        largest=total;
        lp=i;
      }System.out.println(largest);
    }`

Comment: sopln(largest); will be outside for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can save the outPut  at every step in to a priority queue(which saves the elements in natural ordering) and in the last step the pull() the highest value from this priority queue.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] arg){

    int[][] studentMarksArray = new int[10][3];

    PriorityQueue<Double> pq = new PriorityQueue<Double>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]*studentMarksArray[i][1]*studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
      System.out.println(total);
      pq.add(total);
     }
    System.out.println(pq.poll());;
}
}
```